# Swift : Game starts to lag mid way

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know this is a little vague, but my game starts to lag about mid way and I'm trying to figure out why. Its a simple game where the user taps the left and right sides of the screen as fast as they can and a set of frames animate per click.The game runs perfectly in the beginning but once it gets midway, it starts to slow down to the point its noticeable. I checked the memory and its constant throughout the lifespan of the game so i don't believe its a memory leak. Any ideas to where I should look and what the problem could possibly be?

Image of memory(maybe Im not reading it correctly and I do have a leak?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a strong retain cycle.

Something like: GameScene has a reference to a nodeA that has a reference to nodeB.

Start by adding a print inside the deinit of every class you defined

```
class SpriteA: SKSpriteNode {
    deinit {
        print(String(SpriteA) + " deallocated")
    }
}
```

This way you can check if your objects are actually removed from memory.